# Android release apk proguard issues

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-proguard

i have updated my Android studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1.2 and my Gradle version as well from 4.1 to 4.4 
every this went find unless releasing signed APK, I'm always having the same issues

### Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

My Gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.***.***'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26 
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.5.07.180521"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resValue("string", "PORT_NUMBER", "15711")
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "qs_${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }

    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'classes.dex'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.8.0'
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    implementation'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation project(path: ':quayosolution')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My Log file during generating signed APK can be found [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wN80rTMvkE-LZTZZPxThu-PGIN0hmKlU/view?usp=sharing), but the end of log is

```
Warning: there were 779 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 68 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
40 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 38 up-to-date
```

I tried to add

> -dontwarn
>   to my proguard-rules.pro but nothing changed.

NOTE: im able to generate APK when is set minifyEnabled to false, but the APK size is larger than expected.

Comment: it requires to mention all classes or package in proguard-rules.pro file that it should not be minified, you will get that information from whatever library that you have used, as you can see in http://square.github.io/retrofit/ at end of the page

Comment: actually my progurad file is empty, all lines are commented

Comment: yes, but you have to mention all the classes then proguard will work because you are using some of the libraries.

Comment: can you support me for this

Comment: for that i need to check source code, then i can help

Comment: you can't get what needed from the log and the Gradle ? my cod is huge, it's more than 15 Mb of code.

Comment: Its not an easy to make proguard enable, we can not guess anything from error.